# correlation in matlab between two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

[image]

Hi,

1. I would like to create a correlation matrix between the two data set presented above that will ignore any appearances of zeros (in the picture above, the green color), anyone knows what is the most efficient way that will produce a smooth result?
2. Is there any correlation method that can identify the similarity point by point and by thus the results will have the "shape" of the original matrix?

thank u

note: I do not have the matlab statistic toolbox

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. What do you mean "_ignore any appearnaces of zeros_"?

Comment: If u will look at the picture above, besides the "zeros" at the top left part of the picture, the are zeros scattered around, I do not want to exclude them from the data used for the correlation

Comment: What should be the dimension of the result in 1.? I'm asking because a correlation normally takes two vectors and computes a single scalar from it.

Comment: @Mehrwolf, the result should be a m*m matrix with a highest coefficiant in the diagonal. m is the columns

Answer (score 6):

```
2. Is there any correlation method that can identify the similarity point by 
   point  and by thus the results will have the "shape" of the original matrix?
```

Let's start with your second point because it is more clear, what you want there. You want to do a point-by-point comparison of two images, say, `A` and `B`. This boils down to measuring the similarity of two scalars `a` and `b`. Let's assume that these scalars are from the interval `[0, Q]`, where `Q` depends on your image format (`Q == 1` or `Q == 255` are common in Matlab).

Now, the simplest measure of distance is the difference `d = |a - b|`. You might want to normalize this to `[0, 1]` and also invert the values to measure *similarity* instead of *distance*. In Matlab:

```
S = 1 - abs(A - B) / Q;
```

You mentioned about ignoring the zeros in the images. Well, you need to define, what similarity measure you expect for a zero. One possibility is to set the similarity to zero, whenever one pixel is zero:

```
S(A == 0 | B == 0) = 0;
```

You could also say that the similarity there is undefined and set the similarity to `NaN`:

```
S(A == 0 | B == 0) = nan;
```

Of course, you can also say that the mismatch between 10 and 11 is as bad as the mismatch between 100 and 110. In this case, you could take the distance with respect to the sum `a + b` (known as Bray Curtis normalization or normalized Euclidean metric)

```
D = abs(A - B) ./ (A + B)
S = 1 - D / max(D(:));
```

You run into problems, if both matrices have a zero-value pixel at the same location. Again, there are several possibilities: You can augment the sum with a small positive value `alpha` (e.g. `alpha = 1e-6`) which prevents a division by zero: `D = abs(A - B) ./ (alpha + A + B)`.

Another option is to ignore the infinite values in `D` and add your 'zero-processing' here, i.e.

```
D = abs(A - B) ./ (A + B)
D(A == 0 | B == 0) = nan;
S = 1 - D / max(D(:));
```

You see, there are plenty of possibilities.

```
1. I would like to create a correlation matrix [...]
```

You should definitly think more about this point and come up with a better description of what to compute. If your matrices are of size `m x m`, you have `m^2` variables. From this you could compute a correlation matrix `m^2 x m^2`, which measures the correlation of every pixel to every other pixel. This matrix will also have the largest values in the diagonal (these are the variances). However, I would not suggest to compute the correlation matrix if you only have two realisations.

Another option is to measure the similarity of rows or columns in the two images. Then you end up with a vector `1 x m` of correlation coefficients.

However, I do not know how to compute a correlation matrix of size `m x m` from two inputs of size `m x m`, which has the largest values in the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

To just get a general correlation coefficient I'd use `corr2`. [From the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html):

> `r = corr2(A,B)`
>
> Returns the correlation coefficient r
>   between A and B, where A and B are matrices or vectors of the same
>   size. r is a scalar double.

Roughly, I believe it's just calculating `corr(A(:), B(:))`.